# Microsoft OneDrive and SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to access my files from the MS OneDrive, but in response it gives me the error "Unauthorized Access".
I have refreshed my access token and the app is valid and registered to the MS App Registration Portal.

I have looked over the internet and found no solution.

Please find the code at the [github repository](https://github.com/mohit0094/OneDrive/tree/master).
The methods for concern are **authorize()** and **accessAndRefreshToken()**

Also, I am recieving different errors using different tools.

While using Postman the error is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "729c6cdc-6b9e-4874-b012-5e8bdd2d91da",
      "date": "2017-04-11T17:35:47"
    }
  }
}
```

This error is shown even if I have provided the access token with the request.

While using [onlinecurl.com](http://onlinecurl.com/):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken validation failed with reason code: -2147184088.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3c1f007b-1af8-447a-89c2-eab04bd66d2e",
      "date": "2017-04-11T17:34:26"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how my request looks like:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive
--header Content-Length: 0
--header Authorization: bearer {access_token}
```

I tried using `v2.0` instead of `v1.0` and `Bearer` instead of `bearer`. No luck.

Comment: Please include the code you have, and show where the error occurs and the details of the error (if exception its type etc.).

Comment: Sorry @Richard it's a bit late, I have updated my question. Thanks already!

Answer (score 1):

You've got an combination of older MSA and modern v2 authentication bits going on.

You're `tokenUrl` is incorrect. It should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`.

You're also not requesting any permission scopes. The end result would be a token without the ability to access anything. You'll likely want at least `User.Read` and `Files.ReadWrite`.

Take a look at [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) for a walk through.